# localdate value don't return result

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I use Java 11, spring boot 2.3.4 with jpa (hibernate implementation)

I have an entity

```
public class Prba{
    Long prId;
    Long baId;
    LocalDate startDate;
}
```

My jpql query

```
select 
  prba from Prba prba 
where 
  prba.prId != :prId
and
  prba.baId = :baId
and
  prba.startDate = :date
```

baId, prId are long (number(18,0) in oracle)
date is localdate (date in oracle)

query generated

```
select * from prba
where 
  prba.pr_id != ?
and
  prba.ba_id = ?
and
  prba.start_date = ?
```

I get no result

Without start_date condition I get a row, start_value is 15-08-2020, it's the java value i pass, but i don't get any result

Edit

if i use

to_date(prba.start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY) = TO_DATE ('15-08-20', 'DD-MM-YYYY')

that work

Is there any method to use in jpa when I use localdate

Edit 2

create table prba (
pr_id number(18,0),
ba_id number(18,0),
startDate date
)

Issue it's in orale a time is saved with a date, if you pass by a ui tool to insert data, 00:00:00 for the time will not be used and if you compare you will get wrong date

Comment: where is localdate defined?   This does not make sense. you are specifying a date mask of YYYYY but your example shows a year of 20, not 2020.  Please edit the question and provide all relevant detail included table definition, and example data

Comment: LocalDate is a datatype in Java, is in my entity. make not sense... but it work

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow for the fact that in oracle a DATE data type includes the *time* down to the second.  So if the date in your oracle table has, effectively '23-Sep-2020 15:24:32', and the date you are comparing it to is just a date with no time, then they will not match.  Everything you've presented - especially the use of the to_date to correct it, suggests that is your issue.  BTW,

Here's a demo of what I just said, with an example of the normal adjustment to deal with DATE and ignore the time component:

```
SQL> -- create and populate test table
SQL> create table my_test (dob date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_test values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> -- unconditional select to prove what's there
SQL> select dob,
  2         to_char(dob,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') date_time
  3  from my_test;

DOB       DATE_TIME
--------- --------------------
23-SEP-20 23-sep-2020 15:07:50

1 row selected.

SQL> -- use  where clause that does not account for the time component, it returns nothing
SQL> select dob,
  2         to_char(dob,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') date_time
  3  from my_test
  4  where dob = to_date('23-09-2020','dd-mm-yyyy')
  5  ;

no rows selected

SQL> -- use trun() to eliminate the time component
SQL> select dob,
  2         to_char(dob,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') date_time
  3  from my_test
  4  where trunc(dob) = to_date('23-09-2020','dd-mm-yyyy')
  5  ;

DOB       DATE_TIME
--------- --------------------
23-SEP-20 23-sep-2020 15:07:50

1 row selected.

SQL> -- clean up the test
SQL> drop table my_test purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> spo off
```

Some other observations:

1. your use of "to_date(prba.start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY)" ... the to_date function take a *string* as its input. So if prba.start_date is of data type DATE, you force oracle to first do an implied to_char to make it the string required by to_date. And it is only a matter of time before that comes back to bite you, due to conflicting NLS_ settings.  And if prba.start_date is NOT of data type DATE, then that is in itself a design failure.
2. I'd suggest you give some thought to your naming conventions.

   select
   prba from Prba prba

you have a table name PRBA, in that table you have a column also named PRBA. Not a good idea.  Spend a little time researching column and table naming conventions.